# Libcurl - how to dump debug data to file

Tags: c++, file, curl

I'm using `libcurl` for c++.

I have set to true value `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` but if i make gui app( QT ) and don't have console so all of this information get lost.

I want to have all detailed information (i.e error + information) in file.

Tell me how can i dump all errors+information(just everything) to file?

Comment: CURLOPT_STDERR, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, RTFM.

Comment: @n.m. i use this: `fp_debug = fopen(".\\downloads\\curl_debug.txt","wb");curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, my_trace);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEBUGDATA, &config);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, fp_debug);` and example debug functions from debug example in libcurl  - file created but nothing is written. I think fprintf push data to file stream so i dont know where the problem lies

Comment: Use either DEBUGFUNCTION or STDERR.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example on the curl site showing how you can receive all debug info using the [CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html) option to log it: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/debug.html

Comment: Yes i have got this debugfunction, but now how to dump it to file ?

Comment: easypeacy: fopen() a file and use that returned file handle everywhere where the example code uses `stderr`